# Lower Central Series of Quotient

Tags: group-theory

Let $\gamma_i(G)$ be the $i$th term of the lower central series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Lower_central_series) of a group $G$ and $N\leq G$.

Is it the case that, $\gamma_i(G/N)=1$ implies that $\gamma_i(G)\leq N$?

More generally is there a formula that relates the two? For example if $G^{(i)}$ is the $i$th term of the derived series for $G$, then $(G/N)^{(i)}= G^{(i)}N/N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $\gamma_i(G/N)=\gamma_i(G)N/N$ and $(G/N)^{(i)}=G^{(i)}N/N$ inductively:

Both hold by definition for $i=0$, so take $i\ge 0$.

$\begin{array}{ll}
\gamma_{i+1}(G/N) &=[\gamma_i(G/N),G/N]\\
 &=[\gamma_i(G)N/N,G/N]\\
 &=\{[g_iN,gN]|g_i\in\gamma_i(G),g\in G\}\\
 &=\{[g_i,g]N|g_i\in\gamma_i(G),g\in G\}\\
 &=[\gamma_i(G),G]N/N\\
 &=\gamma_{i+i}(G)N/N\\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ll}
(G/N)^{(i+1)} &=[(G/N)^{(i)},(G/N)^{(i)}]\\
 &=[G^{(i)}N/N,G^{(i)}N/N]\\
 &=\{[gN,hN]|g,h\in G^{(i)}\}\\
 &=\{[g,h]N|g,h\in G^{(i)}\}\\
 &=[G^{(i)},G^{(i)}]N/N\\
 &=G^{(i+i)}N/N\\
\end{array}$